# Best way of editing entire row in a datagrid on wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, edit

What is the best way of editing a entire row on datagrid. Datagrid is bind to sql table. I would like to edit the changes and commit the changed field.

If possible a simple and easy solution for this problem would be gr8 if anyone could suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I quit using DataGrid for editing.  I use the ListView then provide then provide a GridView as the ListView.View.  Inside the GridView you can create GridViewColumns with CellTemplates.  The last column of each GridView row is a button to delete that row. Instead of supporting a browse and edit mode, I just support an edit mode.  The application moves more fluidly and I don't have any of the headaches that comes along with working with the DataGrid.